# Regex, match text inside a tag, then match all text not in that tag both from same string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I suck at Regex's and am surprised I was able to get as far as I did by myself.

So far I've got this:

```
string text = "Whoa here is some very cool text.<phone>222-222-5555</phone><timesCalled>6</timescalled>";

Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(@"<phone>(.*?)<\/phone>");
Regex calledRegex = new Regex(@"<timesCalled>(.*?)<\/timesCalled>");
string phone = phoneRegex.Match(text).Value;
string timesCalled = calledRegex.Match(text).Value;
```

Both of these give me the full tags and the value inside, how do I make it so it only returns what is inside the tag? **Also I need a final regex that would return all the text not inside those tags, so `Whoa here is some very cool text.` from the above example.** The special tags would always appear after the normal text, if that matters.

Edit: Thanks for the answers all, I still need the final regex though (bolded above).

So far I tried this:

```
 string pattern = @"^" + phoneRegex.Match(text).Value + calledRegex.Match(text).Value;
 Regex textRegex = new Regex(pattern);
 string normalText = textRegex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
```

but that is returning nothing.

Comment: Is this *actually* HTML/XML? If so, I'd strongly suggest *not* trying to parse it with a regex to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the value of the group:

```
calledregex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value
```

Groups are 1-based.

Answer (score 1):

How about reading/parsing XML with an Xml class?

```
var doc = XElement.Parse("<root>" + text + "</root>");
string phone = doc.Descendants("phone").First().Value;
```

Comment: It's not _valid_ XML. But what do you call it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, gives you the chance to serach for more tags with values.

```
 string text = "Whoa here is some very cool text.<phone>222-222-5555</phone><timesCalled>6</timesCalled>";

 Regex regex = new Regex(@"<(?<tag>[^>]*)>(?<value>[^<]*)</\k<tag>>");
 Match match = regex.Match(text);
 string phone = match.Groups["value"].Captures[match.Groups["tag"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == "phone").Index].Value;
 string timesCalled = match.Groups["value"].Captures[match.Groups["tag"].Captures.OfType<Capture>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == "timesCalled").Index].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Value` of a match is everything that matched the pattern.  If you only want the grouped contents (the stuff within the tags), you'd have to access them through the `Groups` property.

```
string phone = phoneRegex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
string timesCalled = calledregex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of inline xml/html I would also ignore case, tag capitalization can be wonky sometimes.

```
string text = "Whoa here is some very cool text.<phone>222-222-5555</phone><timesCalled>6</timesCalled>";

Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(@"<phone>(.*?)<\/phone>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex calledRegex = new Regex(@"<timesCalled>(.*?)<\/timesCalled>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string phone = phoneRegex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
string timesCalled = calledRegex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
```